# JPA Entities - MySQL tables Mapping

Tags: mysql, hibernate, orm, jpa

***Database tables:***

1. Tutor( {PK}tutorId, name )
2. Module( {PK}moduleId, name, {FK}tutorId )

*Relationship Tutor -> Module (OneToMany)*

***Questions:***

1. If you create the domain model
   classes with JPA annotations, the
   corresponding database tables are
   auto-created with the same columns as the annotated fields of the class?
2. Do you create the database first
   and then the JPA classes with the
   same fields as the database table
   columns?
3. How do you model *foreign key constraints* with JPA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) and (2) are depended on your situation. you can create domain model class first and it will generate table and columns which are the similar to the fields. In addition, you can establish a database first (it is easy to design and have better view of the whole database.), then map the tables to your domain class.

about (3) you can try this  [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association)

Comment: Do i need to establish the database first in order to create tables/columns in it?